# How to pass multiple uploaded files from view to controller in MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm able to pass file if there's only a single file upload control but, when I use multiple file upload controls I get null.

This is my View : -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page - My ASP.NET MVC Application
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexFeatured" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>

   <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input type="file" name="files1" value="" multiple="multiple"/>

     <input type="file" name="files2" value="" multiple="multiple"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload You Image"  title="Uplad"/>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the Controller Action:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                /*Geting the file name*/
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                /*Saving the file in server folder*/
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                string filepathtosave = "Images/" + filename;
                /*HERE WILL BE YOUR CODE TO SAVE THE FILE DETAIL IN DATA BASE*/
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: In my memory, try to modify the input name to files.

Comment: How do you expect that your `files1` and `files2` were bound to `files`? MVC has naming conventions, so try to rename your controls to `files` and see what you get. Also you can look at `Request.Form` to see what you really has on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do in your case is iterate through `Request.Files`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in Request.Files)
    {
        ...
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

asp.net mvc modelbinding takes into account the name of input fields. The parameter of your action method matches with none of the input file fields. You need to modify them like

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase[] files1, HttpPostedFileBase[] files2)
        {
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files1)
            {
                /*Geting the file name*/
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                /*Saving the file in server folder*/
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                string filepathtosave = "Images/" + filename;
                /*HERE WILL BE YOUR CODE TO SAVE THE FILE DETAIL IN DATA BASE*/
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Or if you want to receive all files in same parameter you can make your inputs like

```
 <input type="file" name="files[0]" value="" multiple="multiple"/>

     <input type="file" name="files[1]" value="" multiple="multiple"/>
```

With this, you wouldn't need to change the implementation of your action method